# Image displayed is not fixed (changes in seconds) - PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

traffic* are variable storing the images of traffic.

```
traffic1 = pygame.image.load("traffic-1.png")
traffic2 = pygame.image.load("traffic-2.png")
traffic3 = pygame.image.load("traffic-3.png")
traffic4 = pygame.image.load("traffic-4.png")
traffic5 = pygame.image.load("traffic-5.png")
```

def traffic is taking two arguments x and y for pixels, and it displays the image of the traffic on the screen.

```
def traffic(traffic_x, traffic_y):
    traffic_list = [traffic1, traffic2, traffic3, traffic4, traffic5]
    gameDisplay.blit(traffic_list[random.randint(0, 4)], (traffic_x, traffic_y))
```

Problem: When the function is executed, it displays the images randomly of all the traffic i.e. iterate through the complete list in one go.
I want that a single image appears per display and the traffic images display in a random order.
Checkout the game play gif to understand correctly.

Complete code:
http://txt.do/dp5c6

Github link:
https://github.com/siddhantsar/Road-Racer-PyGame

Gameplay:
https://giphy.com/gifs/2sh4xKQNroQCQOcRZI

Answer (score 0):

You're calling random.randint inside traffic. Every time you call it, it generates a new random integer for you, thus selecting a random image to display each time you call traffic.

To fix this, randomly choose your image ahead of time (For example when you reset the car to the top of the screen) and save it in a variable. Then pass that variable to traffic.

```
def traffic(traffic_x, traffic_y, traffic_image):
    gameDisplay.blit(traffic_image, (traffic_x, traffic_y))

# ...

traffic_list = [traffic1, traffic2, traffic3, traffic4, traffic5]

# ...

car_image = traffic_list[random.randint(0, 4)]

# ... call traffic(x, y, car_image) multiple times ...
```